# solidity delegatecall Error return value

Tags: solidity, delegatecall

```
function queryErc20BaseInfo(address a) public view returns(bool success, bytes memory list )
{
    (success , list) = address(a).staticcall(abi.encodeWithSignature("name()"));
    return (success , list);  
}
```

if contract is erc20.. the run return result

{
"0": "string: brBridge Token"
}.

but contract not erc20address.
run then
..
return result is
call to tool.queryErc20BaseInfo errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid address
...

so.  if address is not erc20 address.
I wish to return.
{
"0": "undefined"
}
What should I do?

Comment: Can you share all your smart contract code?

Comment: contract tool {  function queryErc20BaseInfo(address a) public pure returns(bool success, bytes memory returnedData )
{
    return  address(a).delegatecall(abi.encode("name()"));
}  }

Answer (score 0):

First of all , u shouldn't use delegatecall which will execute the target code in your contract storage space and you will not have the desired result returned.

u can do `(bool success, bytes result ) = address(a).call(abi.encode("name()"));` , and from there you can decode the result to see if it is an ERC20 token

Comment: function queryErc20BaseInfo(address a) public view returns(bool success, bytes memory list )
    {
        (success , list) = address(a).staticcall(abi.encodeWithSignature("name()"));
        return (success , list);  
    }

Comment: can return result.. but  address not erc20 contract.. run have error ..

Comment: I think.  batch query contract name。。 If one of the addresses is not a contract address. . An error will be returned. The program will stop running.